# How can I convert a Unicode value to an ASCII string?

Tags: c#, unicode

I am given a Unicode value that contains characters that can be represented as ASCII. How can I get a string containing the ASCII characters from the Unicode value?

Comment: I like how there's four different answers in 4 minutes for such a simple question.

Comment: string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer); buffer is byte array of your unicode value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You would need to covert it by transforming the string into a `byte array`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Encoding.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert%28VS.71%29.aspx) Method

Answer (score 2):

If you have an instance of a string and you want to turn it into an array of bytes containing the values for ASCII characters you can use the GetBytes method of the [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "your text";
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text));
```